# Recognize multiple strings starting with @

Tags: php

I want my php to recognize multiple strings in a string starting with the @ symbol. Those shall then be converted into variables

```
//whole string
$string = "hello my name is @mo and their names are @tim and @tia."
//while loop now?
```

@mo @tim @tia shall then be converted to variables like:

```
$user1 = "mo";
$user2 = "tim";
$user3 = "tia";
```

Is there a php command you can use to collect them all in an array?

Comment: OK, sounds like a great plan. Go! Any questions from your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are a very flexible tool for pattern recognition:

```
<?php
$subject = "hello my name is @mo and their names are @tim and @tia.";
$pattern = '/@(\w+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $tokens);
var_dump($tokens);
```

The output is:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "@mo"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "@tim"
    [2] =>
    string(4) "@tia"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(2) "mo"
    [1] =>
    string(3) "tim"
    [2] =>
    string(3) "tia"
  }
}
```

So `$token[1]` is the array you are interested in.

Comment: Works very well! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you use a regex to match all those string starting with "@" and put it in an array?

```
preg_match_all("|\@(.*)[ .,]|U",
    "hello my name is @mo and their names are @tim and @tia.",
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

`out` now has the matched strings..

> PS: Am not a PHP developer. Just tried out something using online
>   compiler.!